# Getting DeadLock in SQL Server even after restarting server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am getting deadlock error when updating a table :

> Transaction (Process ID 67) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

All other works perfectly fine. The thing making me uncomfortable is I have restarted the server itself 4-5 times how is the dead lock still on table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like an open transaction than needs a `commit` or `rollback`

Comment: How can I narrow it down to that ? As I am only good with making , table and using them when it comes to sql server. (also a little bit of indexing)

Comment: Or you could kill the process (in Activity Monitor)

Comment: Run a script with just `rollback` in it (or `commit`). Can you remember what you were doing before the problem started.

Comment: aa I was sleeping :D came back to this so not a clue :)

Comment: Right mouse click on the server name (top level) in the object browser then click on processes

Comment: Ok yeah, so what am I looking at now? I see most expensive queries it the same query  updated (select)  .... Also something odd looking in the Resources wait for Locks its saying  231038

Comment: You have the ID (in the error message). Just kill the process (another right mouse click)

Comment: There are like 100-120 processes cause we have like 50+ servers connecting to this single DB ? Any way to force close all or I have to do one by one

Comment: Use the database name and the process ID from the error message

Comment: That is saying processID 6 7 and 67 does not exists

Comment: @PeterSmith PID 67 was the deadlock victim that got rolled back.

Comment: Sounds like your table has an update trigger that's trying to insert/update rows in a different table that is then conflicting with other processes. You could try `select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions where open_transaction_count > 0` to look for long-running transactions in other sessions and then investigate what they're doing. If you've rebooted/restarted SQL Server multiple times already it sounds like something (a service/application) has a persistent problem somewhere.

Comment: Deadlocks are most often due to suboptimal plans (scans) that touch more data than needed. Perhaps the plan changed at some point. Add the deadlock xml report to your question (see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281379/catch-deadlock-events-in-a-background-job)) and upload the plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Which exact build number are you on? `select @@version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Transaction (Process ID 67) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources

This is probably caused by a bug while running a parallel query.  Upgrade SQL Server to a later version, or disable parallelism for [this query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#maxdop-integer_value) or the [whole server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15).